# How to add double quote with number when getting from API in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting JSON data from a API but in that API I'm getting number without quote now I need to add quotes how can I added quotes with numbers?

**Right now I'm getting:-**

```
[{"name":"Hakim","age":32},{"name":"Girish","age":35}
```

**I want to get:-**

```
[{"name":"Hakim","age":"32"},{"name":"Girish","age":"35"}
```

**Demo URL:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/double-quote-issue-nkhkye?file=/src/App.js:0-555

**My Code:-**

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const real_data = [
  {
    name: "Hakim",
    age: 32
  },
  {
    name: "Girish",
    age: 35
  }
];
const update_data = JSON.stringify(real_data);
console.log(update_data);
export default function App() {
  //  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  // setData(real_data);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* {data
        ? data.map((opt) => (
            <h2 key={opt.age} value={opt.age}>
              {opt.name}
            </h2>
          ))
        : ""} */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: "Add quotes" where?  For what purpose?  It's not clear to me what you're asking or what problem you're observing.  In general if you want to turn a number into a string then you can append `.toString()` to it.

Comment: let me modify my question to explain what i want to do.

Comment: @David I modified my question can you please recheck?

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  Have you tried using `.toString()` on any given numeric value to convert it to a string?  In what way is the code shown not working?

Comment: console.log(real_data.map(d=> {d.age =d.age.toString(); return d}));

Comment: You're better off fixing the data that's sent to you if you can but it's not clear why you want to add the quotes. Is something not working?

Comment: But Andy's point is valid ...

Comment: yes @Andy somewhere i need to post this data there only accepting with quote.

Comment: @RohitVerma yeah, so it makes sense to fix the original data that way you don't have to do any transformations on the client before posting it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const stringAges = real_data.map(e => ({...e, age: e.age + '' }));
```